# Plotly.js Chart Annotations not aligned

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a heatmap made with plotly.js.

Everything seems to work fine, however the annotations are all on one side. 
resistance
I have a very similar heatmap with the **exact** **same** layout properties and everything works, including the annotations.

This is the "broken" [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u27r8gq5/1/)
And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7f8bhptm/) is the one working fine.

I really can't figure out what I'm missing.

The `layout` is identical on both (the working one uses strings but I also tried with `String(catVar` and `String(i.channel)` but nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'broken' example you are adding `1` to your `xValuesOne` array resp. `2` and `xValuesTwo`. If you exchange both arrays with `['Page Views/Sessions']` resp. `['Avg. Time on Site']` your x-axis should be fine. In your `layout` you are using those two categorical values but you define your x-axis with numbers, either use categorical values or numbers but do not mix them. The same is true for the y-axis.
Also in your broken example you are defining two heatmaps while in the 'working' example there is only one.

---

In the snippet below each heatmap has only one x-value (an array with identical values), `0` for the first heatmap, `1` for the 2nd. The labels for the ticks on the x-axis are set manually to your categories (via `ticktext` and `tickvals`).

I tried to simply your script as much as possible, instead of using two variables they are put into an array, unused variables were removed, etc.

```js
var channels = [{
  "channel": "(Other)",
  "pageviews": 1388082,
  "sessions": 314263,
  "avg_time": 54.94890183937861
}, {
  "channel": "Referral",
  "pageviews": 364869,
  "sessions": 50387,
  "avg_time": 58.104753437736335
}, {
  "channel": "Direct",
  "pageviews": 92538,
  "sessions": 22118,
  "avg_time": 59.21658970091479
}, {
  "channel": "Organic Search",
  "pageviews": 23470,
  "sessions": 4246,
  "avg_time": 51.96215449005384
}, {
  "channel": "Social",
  "pageviews": 8317,
  "sessions": 1931,
  "avg_time": 58.63430399702078
}];

var xValues = [[], []];
var yValues = [];
var zValues = [[], []];
var nc = -1;
var cat = ['Page Views/Sessions', 'Avg. Time on Site'];
var x = 0;
var layout = {
  title: 'Sessions',
  annotations: [],
  xaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    side: 'bottom',
    tickvals: [0, 1],
    tickmode: 'array',
    ticktext: cat
  },
  yaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    ticksuffix: ' ',
    autosize: false
  }
};
var result = {};
var txt;
channels.forEach(function(i) {
  xValues[0].push(0);
  xValues[1].push(1);
  yValues.push(i.channel);
  zValues[0].push(parseInt(i.pageviews / i.sessions));
  zValues[1].push(parseInt(i.avg_time));

  nc++;
  for (x = 0; x < cat.length; x += 1) {
    result = {
      xref: 'x1',
      yref: 'y1',
      x: x,
      y: i.channel,
      text: zValues[x][nc],
      font: {
        family: 'Arial',
        size: 12,
        color: 'rgb(50, 171, 96)'
      },
      showarrow: false
    };
    layout.annotations.push(result);
  }
});

var data = [{
  type: 'heatmap',
  x: xValues[0],
  y: yValues,
  z: zValues[0],
  colorscale: 'Greens',
  showscale: false
}, {
  type: 'heatmap',
  x: xValues[1],
  y: yValues,
  z: zValues[1],
  colorscale: 'Reds',
  showscale: false
}];

Plotly.newPlot('graph', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @maximilian-peters, thanks a lot for the help. I edited the X & Y axis and that indeed helped, however it's still not rendering correctly. The thing is that I need to have 2 heatmaps independent from each other (X1 & X2). This is the edited [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u27r8gq5/3/). Why is still not rendering as it should?

Comment: @Costantin: see updated answer and http://jsfiddle.net/csggefu8/ for minimal changes required to make it work.

Comment: Hi @maximilian-peters, this is fantastic! Thank you SO much! If I can bother you with just one last thing, do you know why the colour don't show up correctly? For example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qcnL8n2c/) the **4**s are completely white, or even on your snippet the **5** is white, do you know why this happens?

Comment: Your `colorscale` gets mapped to the min and max values of your z-values. You can overwrite them with `zmin` and `zmax`, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/zs9m69w9/